# How can I generate random 64-bit signed integer with macOS?

Tags: shell-script, shell, osx, random

I need to generate some 64-bit signed integer for testing.

How can I do this?

```
#!/bin/sh
long=$(????)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine 2 32-bit integers captured from `/dev/urandom`.  It should be possible to use `od` to capture a single 64-bit value per [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332369/181036), but on at least some versions of OS X this fails without an appropriate error message.

```
#!/bin/sh
low32=$(od -An -td4 -N4 < /dev/urandom)
high32=$(od -An -td4 -N4 < /dev/urandom)
long=$(($low32 + ($high32 << 32) ))
```

Answer (score 4):

macOS comes with Python. Use its [`random`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-random.html) module.

```
python -c 'import random; rng = random.SystemRandom(); print rng.randint(-2**63, 2**63-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As macOS has `/dev/urandom`, you should be able to do:

```
od -An -vtd8 -N8 < /dev/urandom
```

However, according to those who've tried it on an actual macOS system (see comments), it doesn't work there. As macOS is meant to be a certified Unix system, that means it's a bug as [POSIX clearly specifies the behaviour of that command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html). The only thing that POSIX leaves unspecified (implementation defined) is the byte order (which we don't care about here as that's all random bytes).

Alternatively, you could use `ksh`/`bash`/`zsh`'s `$RANDOM` here. Even though macOS' `sh` is based on `bash` nowadays, it would be better to switch to bash/zsh (or `ksh` implementations other than `mksh` whose arithmetic use 32bits) as `$RANDOM` is not a `sh` feature so may not work in future version of macOS if they decide to switch to a different shell.

```
m=32768 # $RANDOM span
long=$((RANDOM+RANDOM*m+RANDOM*m*m+RANDOM*m*m*m+RANDOM*m*m*m*m))
```

or:

```
long=$((RANDOM|(RANDOM<<15)|(RANDOM<<30)|(RANDOM<<45)|(RANDOM<<60)))
```

That's 5*15 == 75 bits but that will be truncated to 64 bits by the shell.

In the POSIX tool chest, the way to generate random numbers is with `awk`'s `rand()`, so you could do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand(); printf "%.20g\n", rand() * (2^64) - (2^63)}'
```

Beware though that with many `awk` implementations (those that base the `srand()` seed on the result of `time(3)`), you'll get the same output if you run it twice in the same second.

Also, because of the way floating point numbers are represented, I'd expect there would be some 64bit numbers (like 2<sup>63</sup>-1) that it would never output.

Comment: The command doesn't appear to work as expected.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, in what way? It does work as expected on a GNU system, I don't have a macOS system to test it on, but it seems to me it should work on Unix compliant systems.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas; I also see correct result on GNU/Linux.  On MacOS, this appears to give a signed 8-bit value displayed as 32-bit (i.e., either between 0-127 or 4294967040-4294967295).  Checking on OSX options for od...

Comment: @user4556274, looks like a bug. FreeBSD doesn't support byte counts greater than 4, but at least, it gives you an error when you try to use `-td8` for instance.

Comment: @user4556274, FreeBSD also fails with an error for `-tdL`. What do you get on macOS?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I'd agree it is a bug.  `-tdL` also gives an 8-bit result identical to `-td8`.  `-td4` works as expected.

Comment: And tested on an older Mac (10.5.8), `... -td8 ...` results in `od: unsupported int size 8`.   So at some point they got rid of the error message without fully implementing?  I don't have access to enough machines to find which version made the change.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: You mean `rand() * (2^64) - (2^63)`?

Comment: @cuonglm oops must have been a wrong copy-paste. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can append two 32-bit numbers together, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '0x%04x%04x\n' $RANDOM $RANDOM
j=$(printf '16#%04x%04x' $RANDOM $RANDOM)
echo $j
echo $(($j))
```

Sample output

```
0x5e34562d 
16#7cf567f9
2096457721
```

This is one of many features originating in the Korn shell (ksh), copied to bash and zsh a few years later.

Per comment - you can append additional bits:

```
#!/bin/bash    
printf '0x%04x%04x\n' $RANDOM $RANDOM
foo=32767
printf '%016x\n' $((foo << 49))
printf '%016x\n' $((foo << 34))
printf '%016x\n' $((foo << 19))
printf '%016x\n' $((foo << 4))
printf '%016x\n' $((foo % 16))

printf '%016x\n' $((foo << 49 |
                   (foo << 34) |
                   (foo << 19) |
                   (foo << 4) |
                   (foo % 16)))
printf '%d\n'    $((foo << 49 |
                   (foo << 34) |
                   (foo << 19) |
                   (foo << 4) |
                   (foo % 16)))
```

Sample output:

```
0x3a1e1184     
fffe000000000000
0001fffc00000000
00000003fff80000
000000000007fff0
000000000000000f
ffffffffffffffff
-1
```

Comment: $RANDOM goes from 0 to 32767 though. That's 15 bits. The OP is asking for 64 bits and for _signed_ integers.

Comment: Doing `04x04x` like that for 2 _15 bit_ numbers means bit 15 and 31 of that hex number will always be 0, so you won't cover all the 64 bit spectrum with that approach.